# Size of R/P (P = irrationals)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

What is the size of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{P},$ where $\mathbb{P}=\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$? I would guess countable, but just want to verify, thank you.

Edit:
Define $x \sim y \Leftrightarrow x-y\in \mathbb{P}.$ Then $[x]=\{y:x-y\in\mathbb{P}\},$ and $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{P}=\{[x]:x \in \mathbb{R}\}.$

Edit:
This question is ill-formed because $\sim$ fails reflexivity as well as transitivity. Per David Lui's suggestion I will consider the equivalence closure. So for reflexive closure I would have to add the pair $(x,x)$ to each equivalence class, if I am understanding correctly. For transitive closure, add the pair $(x,z)$ any time that both $x\sim y$ and $y \sim z$, is that correct?

Comment: What does $/$ mean?

Comment: Modulo, or factor group. I will add some clarification.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}$ is not a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$. For instance, it doesn't contain $0$ (so it's not a subgroup of $(\mathbb{R},+)$) or $1$ (so it's not a subgroup of $(\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}, \times)$).

Comment: Although you can consider the equivalence closure of $\{x, y : x - y \notin \mathbb{Q}\}$.

Comment: $\sim$ is not an equivalence relation. For example, it is not true that $x\sim x$, and it is possible that $x\dim y$ and $y\sim z$ but not $x\sim z.$

Comment: Your new definition is still pretty weird because $\sim$ is not an equivalence relation. For example, you have $\sqrt 2 \sim 0 \sim \sqrt{2}+1$ but $\sqrt 2 \not \sim \sqrt{2}+1$. If you try to fix it by taking the "equivalence closure" per David Lui's comment then you'll just end up with one equivalence class total.

Comment: Thanks @DavidClyde, I guess that will end this line of questioning since a single class wouldn't be very useful. I was trying to reformulate the Vitali set construction in a novel way, so sounds like it's back to the drawing board.

Comment: As defined currently, $[x]=[y]$ iff $x-y\in \mathbb Q,$ the opposite of what you'd expect. But that would give you a cardinality of the quotient equal to the cardinality of $\mathbb R.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the given definitions (plus fixes where neeed), the cardinality of $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{P}$ is exactly 1.

In particular, define $x \# y$ if $x - y \not \in \mathbb{Q}$, and then let $\sim$ be the smallest equivalence relation that contains $\#$. Then we have $x \sim y$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. To prove this, we can just show that $0 \sim x$ for an arbitrary fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

If $x$ is irrational, the claim holds because $0 \# x$. If $x$ is rational, then we have $0 \# \sqrt 2 \# x$, which means $0 \sim \sqrt 2 \sim x$, which means $0 \sim x$ by transitivity.

(Moving my comment into an answer so that the question stops appearing as open. Also, thanks to @ArturoMagidin for pointing out some typos in a comment.)

Comment: I think you mean the difference is **not** in $\mathbb{Q}$ (first sentence of third paragraph), and $x\in y$ should be $x\sim y$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks! Edited the answer and credited you.

Comment: Technically, while the definition in the question uses the notation of an equivalence relation and equivalence classes, it never uses the terms, and the definition makes sense as is. It's just the $[x]=[y]$ iff $x-y\in \mathbb Q,$ the opposition of what you'd expect.